# symfony 2.8 FOSUserBundle legacyFormHelper: get input field of form in twig template

Tags: php, forms, symfony-2.8

I am trying to restyle the register form of the FOSUserBundle,
i try to putt the input in my template line by line like this.

```
{{ form_widget(form.username) }}
{{ form_widget(form.first_name) }}
```

This works, but when i try to do this with the password en confirmation password it doesn't work.

Here is the line of the form builder:

```
->add('plainPassword', LegacyFormHelper::getType('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType'), array(
        'type' => LegacyFormHelper::getType('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType'),
        'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
        'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
        'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
        'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
```

I try to put it in the temlate like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword) }}
{{ form_widget(form.password_confirmation) }}
```

but it is not working, i tried some other things also but i cant figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question:

```
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }}
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second) }}
```

Full information about the register template customization can be found here:

https://www.amalhichri.net/user-management-with-fosuserbundle/